# Как вывести массив в foreach с особым вложением?

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Есть массив состоящий из родительских и дочерних строк:

```
$arr = array(
    6 => array('p_id' => 0, 'name' => 'Размер:'),
    10 => array('p_id' => 6, 'name' => 'больше'),
    11 => array('p_id' => 6, 'name' => 'меньше'),
    29 => array('p_id' => 0, 'name' => 'Длина:'),
    32 => array('p_id' => 29, 'name' => 'короче'),
    33 => array('p_id' => 29, 'name' => 'длиннее'),
);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как пересобрать массив, чтобы добавить в родительские индексы дочерние строки, и привести к данному виду

```
Array
(
    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => Размер:
            [item] => Array
                (
                    [10] => больше
                    [11] => меньше
                )
        )
    [29] => Array
        (
            [name] => Длина:
            [item] => Array
                (
                    [32] => короче
                    [33] => длиннее
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Это принципиально, чтобы индексы были 6, 10, 11 и т.д.? Нельзя там сделать очередные индексы 0, 1, 2 и т.д., а эти перенести в массивы в отдельную ячейку, например ```id```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если принципиально, чтобы индексы были именно такими, как у Вас в примере, то:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    6 => array('p_id' => 0, 'name' => 'Размер:'),
    10 => array('p_id' => 6, 'name' => 'больше'),
    11 => array('p_id' => 6, 'name' => 'меньше'),
    29 => array('p_id' => 0, 'name' => 'Длина:'),
    32 => array('p_id' => 29, 'name' => 'короче'),
    33 => array('p_id' => 29, 'name' => 'длиннее'),
);

foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    $arr[$key]['id'] = $key;
}

foreach($arr as $old_Arr){
    if($old_Arr["p_id"] == 0){
        $old_Arr["item"] = array();
        $new_Arr[] = $old_Arr;
    }
}
for($i = 0; $i < count($new_Arr); $i++){
    foreach($arr as $old_Arr){
        if($new_Arr[$i]["id"] == $old_Arr["p_id"]){
            $new_Arr[$i]["item"][$old_Arr["id"]] = $old_Arr["name"];
        }
    }
}
foreach($new_Arr as $new){
    $array[$new["id"]] = [
        'name' => $new["name"],
        'item' => $new["item"]
    ];
}

print_r($array);
```

Если индексы не важны, можно использовать и упорядоченные, то:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    6 => array('p_id' => 0, 'name' => 'Размер:'),
    10 => array('p_id' => 6, 'name' => 'больше'),
    11 => array('p_id' => 6, 'name' => 'меньше'),
    29 => array('p_id' => 0, 'name' => 'Длина:'),
    32 => array('p_id' => 29, 'name' => 'короче'),
    33 => array('p_id' => 29, 'name' => 'длиннее'),
);

foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    $arr[$key]['id'] = $key;
}

foreach($arr as $old_Arr){
    if($old_Arr["p_id"] == 0){
        $old_Arr["item"] = array();
        $new_Arr[] = $old_Arr;
    }
}
for($i = 0; $i < count($new_Arr); $i++){
    foreach($arr as $old_Arr){
        if($new_Arr[$i]["id"] == $old_Arr["p_id"]){
            $new_Arr[$i]["item"][] = $old_Arr["name"];
        }
    }
}

print_r($new_Arr);
```

Comment: Благодарю! На Вашем примере более менее понял логику, как работать с вложениями в массивы.